# RegEx Parse Tool to extract digits from string

Tags: regex, parsing, alteryx

Using Alteryx, I have a field called Address which consists of fields like A32C, GH2X, ABC19E. So basically where digits are pinned between sets of letters. I am trying to use the RegEx tool to extract the digits out into a new column called ADDRESS1.

I have Address set to Field to Parse. Output method Parse.
My regular expression is typed in as:

```
(?:[[alpha]]+)(/d+)(?:[[alpha]]+)
```

And then I have (/d+) outputting to ADDRESS1. However, when I run this it parses 0 records. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a digit, use `[0-9]` or `\d`. To match a letter, use `[[:alpha:]]`.

Use

```
[[:alpha:]]+(\d+)[[:alpha:]]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7stEvh/1).

Comment: Silly me, I was forgetting my colons either side of the alpha! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
let regex = /(?!([A-Z]+))(\d+)(?=[A-Z]+)/g;
let values = 'A32CZ, GH2X, ABC19E'

let result = values.match(regex);

console.log(result);
```